# How to custom place an item in StaggeredGridLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `RecyclerView` that holds user hobbies in profile `fragment`. I placed items in `RecyclerView` with `StaggeredGridLayout`. Like this:

[image]

But I want to show my items a little bit of custom view. The custom view I want:

[image]

And this is my item XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/hobby_profile_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/hobby_background_3"
    android:text="Spor"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:textSize="11sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:fontFamily="@font/inter_semibold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

HobbyAdapter:

```
public class ProfileHobbyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProfileHobbyViewPager> {

private ArrayList<ProfileHobby> hobby_title;

public ProfileHobbyAdapter(ArrayList<ProfileHobby> hobby_title) {
    this.hobby_title = hobby_title;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ProfileHobbyViewPager onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.profil_hobby_card, parent, false);
    ProfileHobbyViewPager profileHobbyViewPager = new ProfileHobbyViewPager(view);
    return profileHobbyViewPager;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProfileHobbyViewPager holder, int position) {
    holder.hobby_profile_title.setText(hobby_title.get(position).getHobby_title());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return hobby_title.size();
}
}
```

Can I get this view using StaggeredGrid? Or should I look for another alternative? Thank you for helpings.

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: @AgentP Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

you'd better use GridLayoutManager instead of StaggeredGridLayout

I think following code will solve your problem:

in kotlin:

```
 val layoutManager= GridLayoutManager(activity, 3)
 layoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
 override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
    return when (position % 2) {
        0 -> 2  //in even rows you have two columns
        else -> 3 //in odd rows you have three columns
       }
   }
}
recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
```

in java:

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);

layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        switch (position % 2) {
        case 0: return 2; //in even rows you have two columns
        case 1: return 3; //in odd rows you have two columns
       
        }
    }
});

recyclerview.setlayoutmanager(layoutManager)
```

in this code, first grid layout has been created with 3 columns, then even rows (even position which specified by position % 2) will return 2 spans and odd rows will show 3 spans.